# How to make my logo and cursor responsive?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I would like some help please with this page.
It works on laptop and desktop, and on mobile version too, but when i shift through the different window sizes, through all the sizes between the mobile and the desktop version, my logo and my cursor won't stay still at the same position, and they both move to the right all over the window! I will post a video link so you can understand exactly what i mean.
I know that there is something wrong with my code but i can not understand how to fix this.
As you will see on the video link, and on JSFiddle link as well, as i resize the window, the logo is gone to the right, it is somewhere on the right side of the page, and the cursor is not under the word "PRESS" but it is under the word "ENTER" and it moves to the right as long as i resize the window. The logo and the cursor will stay still only when i am on mobile-mode and on desktop-mode.
Thank you in advance!!

[Video Link](https://filebin.net/7h33ilqny662kokg)

[JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/ronLfjgu/)

This is my JS and CSS and below them is my HTML.

```js
<script>
          $(function() {
        var cursor;
        $('#cmd').click(function() {
          $('input').focus();
          cursor = window.setInterval(function() {
            if ($('#cursor').css('visibility') === 'visible') {
              $('#cursor').css({
                visibility: 'hidden'
              });
            } else {
              $('#cursor').css({
                visibility: 'visible'
              });
            }
          }, 500);

        });

        $('input').keyup(function() {
          $('#cmd span').text($(this).val());
        });

        $('input').blur(function() {
          clearInterval(cursor);
          $('#cursor').css({
            visibility: 'visible'
          });
        });
      });



      $( document ).ready(function() {
        $( "#cmd").trigger( "click" );
      });


    </script>
```

```css
/*My Index */

#MyBackground {
    
    opacity: 0.6;
 
    /* Pacific Dream */
    background: #34e89e; 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #0f3443, #34e89e);  
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #0f3443, #34e89e);  
}

/* Aurora Logo */
.OurLogo {
    width: 10%;
    margin-left: 75em;
    margin-top: 11em;
}
    

html{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
 }
 
 body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 } 


.containersearchfunction{
  
  position: absolute;
  
 
}

/* The Main Text */
.EnterAText {
    color: rgb(144, 144, 160);
    text-align: center;
   
}
input.form-control.border-0 {
   
    background-color: white;
    
    height: 10em;
}
h2 {
    margin-top: 7em;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    
}

#cmd {
    font-family: courier;
    font-size: 14px;
    background: black;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #cmd span {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 3px;
    white-space: pre;
  }
  #cursor {
  
    width: 1px;
    height: 84px;
    /* background: #21f838; */
    background: #FFFFFF;
    
  }
  input {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    
  }
  div#cmd {
    padding-left: 10em;
    background: transparent;
  
    font-size: 4em;
  }

  /* When i resize the page */
  @media(max-width: 767px){
    div#cmd {
        padding-left: 4em;
        font-size: 4em;
      }
      

      .OurLogo {
        width: 10%;
        margin-left: 24em;
        margin-top: 9em;
        width: 20%;
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
   integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
   integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 

 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.js"></script>
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">

 <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <title>Aurora 4.0 Search Button Page</title>
</head>

<body id="MyBackground">
    

  <div container-fluid class="containersearchfunction">
    <div class="specific-div">
      <div class="EnterAText">
        <h2>TYPE AND PRESS “ENTER” TO SEARCH</h2>
        
        <div id="cmd">
          <span></span>
          <div id="cursor"> </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      <input type="text;" name="command" value=""/>
    </div>
    <div><img class="OurLogo" src="aurora_logoFINAL-01.png" alt="AuroraLogo"></div>
  </div>
           
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Since you want your logo in the bottom-right of your screen(viewport) at all times, you could try replacing your current logo-style with something like this - `.OurLogo{position: fixed; right:10px; bottom:10px;}`

Comment: Unfortunately this works only to a certain point, not at all times as i resize the window..

Comment: Your snippet does not work here, I see an error.  You'll get a better response if you can create a *minimal* working example, eg on JSFiddle, that we can play with and investigate.

Comment: Just did it! Thanks for the information!!

Comment: @Don'tPanic He needs to put his code here and Not a jsfiddle

Comment: @Rob You must have misunderstood my comment.

Comment: The code is here and on jsfiddle as well

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody answered my question, and since i think that i found the answer, i would like to post my updated code which seems to work and it does exactly what i wanted.
I do not know if the code is correct, although it does exactly what i wanted, so if it is not, please correct me!

Here is the video link of how it looks now! Check out the cursor and the logo.
They stay still as i shift through the page from mobile to desktop version.

[Video Link](https://filebin.net/o6wp6pi2uivm6562)

Below is my JS, my CSS and my HTML

```js
  <script>
      $(function() {
        var cursor;
        $("#cmd").click(function() {
          $("input").focus();
          cursor = window.setInterval(function() {
            if ($("#cursor").css("visibility") === "visible") {
              $("#cursor").css({
                visibility: "hidden"
              });
            } else {
              $("#cursor").css({
                visibility: "visible"
              });
            }
          }, 500);
        });

        $("input").keyup(function() {
          $("#cmd span").text($(this).val());
        });

        $("input").blur(function() {
          clearInterval(cursor);
          $("#cursor").css({
            visibility: "visible"
          });
        });
      });

      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#cmd").trigger("click");
      });
    </script>
```

```css
.banner {
  height: 0px;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 13em auto 40px auto;
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
}

.center-me {
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: auto;
}

#MyBackground {
  opacity: 0.6;
  background: #34e89e;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #0f3443, #34e89e);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #0f3443, #34e89e);
}

#cmd {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#cmd span {
  margin-top: -0.4em;
  white-space: pre;
}
#cursor {
  width: 1px;
  height: 84px;
  margin-top: 0em;
  /* background: #21f838; */
  background: #ffffff;
}
input {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-top: -1em;
}
div#cmd {
  padding-left: 2em;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 4em;
}

/* Aurora Logo */
img.OurLogo {
  max-width: 10%;
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body id="MyBackground">
    <div class="banner">
      <div class="center-me">
        <h2>TYPE AND PRESS “ENTER” TO SEARCH</h2>
        <div id="cmd">
          <span></span>
          <div id="cursor"></div>
          <input type="text;" name="command" value="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <footer>
      <div class="logo">
        <img class="OurLogo" src="aurora_logoFINAL-01.png" alt="AuroraLogo" />
      </div>
    </footer>
  
    <input type="text" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();" />
  
  </body>
</html>
```